# Use of indexers on properties in a customer class

Tags: c#, properties, indexer

Been google.ing for some time now and nothing seems to match my specific issue.

I have created my own class with some properties such as

```
public class cPerson
{
  public int? iID {get;set;}
  public string sName { get; set; }
  public bool? bGoodGuy { get; set; }
}
```

then i create an instance of this class

```
cPerson myPerson = new cPerson()
```

and add values

```
myPerson.iID=10;
myPerson.sName="John Smith";
myPerson.bGoodGuy=true;
```

and then if i want to display this person i would do

```
writeline("Persons id : " + myPerson.iID);
writeLine("Persons name : " + myPerson.sName);
writeLine("Person is good : " + myPerson.bGoodGuy);
```

But what i would like is to write it out based on what order the property is defined in my class so

```
writeline("Persons id : " + myPerson[0]);
writeLine("Persons name : " + myPerson[1]);
writeLine("Person is good : " + myPerson[2]);
```

And this is not working.

I just assume that this is doable  with an indexer of some sort, however the samples i have found is for indexing several persons, such as:

```
writeLine("Person 0's id is : " + myPerson[0].iID);
writeLine("Person 0's name is : " + myPerson[0].sName);
writeLine("Person 0's good or bad status is : " + myPerson[0].bGoodGuy);
```

But that is NOT what im after.

Some one (C#) sharp enough to give me some direction i would very much appreciate it.

Regards

A Swede

Comment: First I would ask why you want to do this as it means you can't do any type checking. Also, when you add a new property later on (which you inevitably will) the order might change so `myPerson[1]` is currently the name but in future it could be their title.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons for doing this as i am working hard to get a generic solution to 'fit all' ,perhaps my mind is screwed up but it works and will work like a charm in the future, the solution i went for lies in each class-file as well so there is no issue on correcting any indexes to get the proper value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this seems like a generally bad idea. If you find yourself really needing this, you should carefully consider design alternatives.

Secondly, it's not clear that you can get the properties *in declaration order* - I would strongly consider a more clear-cut ordering, such as alphabetical.

If you *really* want to do this, you can add an indexer like this:

```
public object this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        // Alternative: remove the hard-coding, and fetch the properties
        // via reflection.
        switch(index)
        {
            // Note: property names changed to conform to .NET conventions
            case 0: return Id;
            case 1: return Name;
            case 2: return GoodGuy;
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
        }
    }
}
```

... but as I say, I wouldn't do this.

An alternative would be to have a `Properties` property or method which created an `IEnumerable<object>`, possibly via reflection. For example:

```
public IEnumerable<object> Properties()
{
    return typeof(Person).GetProperties()
                         .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                         .Select(p => p.GetValue(this, null));
}
```

You could then use:

```
Console.WriteLine("Persons id : " + myPerson.Properties().ElementAt(0));
```

Further, if you *really* wanted to, you could make this an extension method on *any* object. Again, I'd be wary of doing any of this though.

Comment: Beat me to it, you are so fast. If this is only for `string` representations, the signature could be `public string this[int index]` and he could call to string in every `return` statement.

Comment: Mein got in der himmel how fast i got the reply i was looking for...i went for your solution public object this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        // Alternative: remove the hard-coding, and fetch the properties
        // via reflection.
        switch(index)
        {
            // Note: property names changed to conform to .NET conventions
            case 0: return Id;
            case 1: return Name;
            case 2: return GoodGuy;
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
        }
    }
}

Comment: @user3755504: Fast? That was nearly 6 minutes! I should be hanging my head in shame ;) Still, I hope you're really thinking about whether or not this is a good idea...

Comment: Agree with @JonSkeet, just because you CAN do something doesn't mean you SHOULD do it. This is the kind of code that can return someday and bite you in the backside.